# function with $(this).attr('src'); undefined on img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help on understand how the $(this) work exactly because i can't bring this simple code to work:

HTML:

```
<img style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openfullsize();" src="/customimage/test.png"/>
```

JS:

```
function openfullsize(){
    var path = $(this).attr("src");
    alert(path);
}
```

I wonder if there is anything i'm doing wrong or if I just don't understand how $(this) behave. $(this) should refer to the element from which it is invoked, right? in this case, it would be my img.

This should alert the content of the src attribute but it is undefined.

I would like this to be in Jquery please.

Thanks for your help and here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk5p68gf/)

Comment: You're using old-fashioned event binding with your jQuery. It would work as you expect if you bound the event handler in JavaScript (via jQuery) instead of with an "onclick" attribute.

Comment: There is a lot going wrong here :P The event handler is in window.load in your jsfiddle, so that means it will not be seen on click. Inside of that handler, since it wasn't assigned using javascript `this` is window, so there is that. jQuery in your fiddle was never included either. Basically, you need to just add jquery, avoid inlining your event handler, and once you have converted to unobtrusive with a jquery or native handler, `this` will properly apply to the element and vuala, src will be available.

Comment: @MaxZoom Why ask for jsFiddles if we have snipplets ;) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @k0pernikus there was some code to display results in the snippet window. Do you know where to get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the event-handler directly in the JS code instead of in the HTML like you're doing at the moment.

```
$("img").on("click", function(){
    //$(this) will now work as expected
});
```

Comment: Working nice and very well. Really like this. Thank you!